# In C#, what would a Timespan.FromSeconds(-1) mean when used in a comparison?

Tags: c#, timespan

Some code I was reading recently did a time calculation something like:

if (TimeWhenResponseArrived - TimeWhenRequested > Timespan.FromSeconds(-1))

I am having a hard time understanding what is trying to be done here. Are they subtracting the times and basically trying to see if they are less than 1 second apart?

Comment: Note that can be rewritten as `TimeWhenRequested < TimeWhenResponseArrived  + Timespan.FromSeconds(1)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Subtracting one DateTime variable from another one will return you a TimeSpan typed result. The code compares the result to decide if the difference is more than a second.

Comment: Ok, that helps. I did read that Timespan.FromSeconds with negative numbers creates a "postive" time span. I really wish they would have written the code with actual intent instead like maybe used Timespan.Duration or something instead. I found it very hard to read

Comment: TimeSpan from a negative does create a negative span, so they're saying "if the response came after the request, or less then one second before". There must be some case where the arrived/requested times are off by a few milliseconds and they wanted to handle that.